# Optimizar consulta MYSQL (registros muy lentos)

Tags: mysql

buenas tardes, me gustaria saber si me podrian ayudar a optimizar mi consulta. Ya que en en tablas regularmente grandes de mas de 1000 registros esta tardando mucho en listar los resultados. Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
$q_juegos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE status=1 and cat_id = 1 and liga_id='2' and fecha = curdate()");
```

Agradesco mucho la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: mas de mil registros, si no hablas de millones, son pocos. Estas seguro que el problema es el query? y si el problema es el query, necesitariamos saber la cantidad de datos, los indices, la descripcion de la tabla, y el explain plan para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Siempre es recomendado no utilizar **`*FROM`** si no que **`FROM`** nada más, intenta realizar la  sin ello.

Comment: Jeje eso quise decir, son muchos registros!  yo estoy probando en local y mi computadora no es tan mala, tengo un i5 y 8gb mas 1 ssd de 500 no deberia ser por mi pc. Creoq ue es algo en la consulta. En especifico son 900.000 regitros

Comment: La consulta que muestras no tiene nada "optimizable", el problema debe venir por falta de índices, lo único que podría decirte viendo el código es que un buen candidato para incorporarle un índice (si no lo tiene) es `fecha`.

Comment: Incluye la descripción de la estructura de la tabla y sus índices asociados.

Comment: No hay mucho que puedas optimizar a no ser que tengas algún problema con indices o primary keys.  Si ejecutás en el mysql un "explain SELECT * FROM juegos WHERE status=1 and cat_id = 1 and liga_id='2' and fecha = curdate()" , te muestra un detalle de la consulta.